# mypy error when evaluating dict.values() as a list

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I am making sure a values is not present in a list of dict values as well as none. Here is my current approach:

```
from typing import Any,Dict

dictionary: Dict[str, str] = {'a':'1','b':'2'}

class TestClass():

    def __init__(self, a: Any):
        self.a = a

    @property
    def test(self) -> None:
        if a not in [None]+list(dictionary.values()):
            raise
```

This results in the error `Argument 1 to "list" has incompatible type "ValuesView[str]"; expected "Iterable[None]"`, but works at runtime. Do I have to change the way this function works or is there a different way to resolve this?

Comment: `a` is not defined inside your `test` definition.

Comment: ``if a is not None and a not in dictionary.values():``

Comment: If you insist on the list, then ``if a not in [None, *dictionary.values()]:`` works as well. But constructing the entire list just for that check really is a waste; even if MyPy would understand what you are up to it would be a bad idea.